# Problems with manually reading app.settings in c# lib

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I have problems with manually reading application settings in c# lib. I have to retrieve LDAPUser from appsettings section of dll app.config Attached herewith the code sample:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("LDAPUser")]
private string LDAPUser
{
    get
    {
        Configuration config = null;
        string exeConfigPath = this.GetType().Assembly.Location;
        try
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (config != null)
        {
            string myValue = GetAppSetting(config, "LDAPUser");
            return myValue;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

}

string GetAppSetting(Configuration config, string key)
{
    KeyValueConfigurationElement element = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
    if (element != null)
    {
        string value = element.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return value;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `string exeConfigPath = this.GetType().Assembly.Location;` won't return the config file, but the folder where the program resides in.

Comment: It needs to be the path + filename of the executable - not the config-file itself, so `Assembly.Location` should work - if you actually use the executable assembly. =)